# How to check if a file already exists before creating it? (C++, Unicode, cross platform)

Tags: c++, unicode, filesystems, cross-platform, file-exists

I have the following code which works on Windows:

```
bool fileExists(const wstring& src)
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
        return (_waccess(src.c_str(), 0) == 0);
#else   
        // ???? how to make C access() function to accept the wstring on Unix/Linux/MacOS ?
#endif
}
```

How do I make the code work on *nix platforms the same way as it does on Windows, considering that `scr` is a Unicode string and might contain file path with Unicode characters?

I have seen various StackOverflow answers which partly answer my question but I have problems to put it all together. My system relies on wide strings, especially on Windows where file names might contain non-ASCII characters. I know that generally it's better to write to the file and check for errors, but my case is the opposite - I need to skip the file if it already exists. I just want to check if the file exists, no matter if I can read/write it or not.

Comment: `if (std::ifstream(name))` ?

Comment: For the linux case see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470639/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c

Comment: @Heather - won't that automatically try to open the file? What if I don't have write or read access to the existing file - I don't want `fileExists` to return false in that case.

Comment: @TimDave - unfortunately that doesn't explain what should I do with my wstring. `access()` wants `char*` but I can get only `wchar_t*` out of wstring. Is it safe to cast `wstring::c_str()` to `char*` on *nix platforms?

Comment: @Martin So is your question really about how to convert a wstring to a char*?

Comment: @TimDave - close to that, but not exactly. I know that there is no direct safe conversion - some Unicode specific symbols might get corrupted. The question is more like - how do I pass the data stored in wstring (which might contain a filename with Unicode characters) to the `access()` function and ensure that it still works as expected? Or maybe I should use some other *nix specific function if I want to process Unicode filenames?

Comment: @Martin This is a real sticky one since you have to deal with character encoding of the file name.  I am not aware of a standard library implementation that will not drop data that is outside the ASCII character set.  If you can use c++11 you do have better options for converting wchar_t* to char*.

Comment: @Martin Have you seen the example in the link below?  It looks like you could do what you wanted with it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf8_utf16/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45282/discussion-between-timdave-and-martin)

Comment: @martin, I have included some code I carry about with me to check for file existence, and it has worked for me for some time now, let me know how it pans out for you:)

Answer (score 1):

On many filesystems other than FAT and NTFS, filenames aren't exactly well defined as strings. They're technically byte sequences. What those byte sequences mean is a matter of interpretation. A common interpretation is UTF-8-like. Not exact UTF-8, because Unicode specifies string equality regardless of encoding. Most systems use byte equality instead. (Again, FAT and NTFS are exceptions, using case-insensitive comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

A good portable solution I use is to use the following:

```
ifstream my_file(myFilenameHere);
if (my_file.good())
{
  // file exists and do what you need to do when it exists
}
else
{
  // the file doesn't exist do what you need to do to create it etc.
}
```

For example a small file existence checker function could be (this one works in windows, linux and unix):

```
inline bool doesMyFileExist (const std::string& myFilename) 
{
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__posix__) || defined(__linux__ )
 // all UNIXes, POSIX (including OS X I think (cant remember been a while)) and 
 // all the various flavours of Linus Torvalds digital offspring:)

    struct stat buffer;   
    return (stat (myFilename.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);

#elif defined(__APPLE__)|| defined(_WIN32)  
// this includes IOS AND OSX and Windows (x64 and x86)
// note the underscore in the windows define, without it can cause problems
    if (FILE *file = fopen(myFilename.c_str(), "r")) 
    {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
#else  // a catch-all fallback, this is the slowest method, but works on them all:)
    ifstream myFile(myFilename.c_str());
    if (myFile.good()) 
    {
      myFile.close();
      return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
      myFile.close();
      return false;
    }   
#endif
}
```

The function above uses the fastest possible method to check the file for each OS variant, and has a fallback in case you are on an os other than the ones explicitly listed (original Amiga OS for example).  This has been used in GCC4.8.x and VS 2010/2012.

The [good](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) method will check that everything is as it should be, and this way you actually have the file open.

The only caveat is pay close attention to how the file name is represented in the OS (as mentioned in another answer).

So far this has worked cross platform for me just fine:)

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately it has two problems why I cannot use it: 1) I want to know that the file exists even if I have no permissions to open it - `fopen` won't work for me, 2) it might not work on Windows if filename contains Unicode characters, e.g, āēīабвгд. I live in a country where we are used to Latvian and Russian filenames with symbols which come from different ANSI codepages, and thus only Windows Unicode API is able to deal with them correctly.

Comment: Ahh I see now, leave it with me and I will have a bash at making something more unicode sensitive tonight:)

Answer (score 1):

I spent some hours experimenting on my Ubuntu machine. It took many trials and errors but finally I got it working. I'm not sure if it will work on MacOS or even on other *nixes.

As many suspected, direct casting to `char*` did not work - then I got only the first slash of my test path `/home/progmars/абвгдāēī` . The trick was to use `wcstombs()` combined with `setlocale()` Although I could not get the text to display in console after this conversion, still `access()` function got it right.

Here is the code which worked for me:

```
bool fileExists(const wstring& src)
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS

    return (_waccess(src.c_str(), 0) == 0);

#else   
    // hopefully this will work on most *nixes...

    size_t outSize = src.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) + 1;// max possible bytes plus \0 char
    char* conv = new char[outSize]; 
    memset(conv, 0, outSize);

    // MacOS claims to have wcstombs_l which has locale argument, 
    // but I could not find something similar on Ubuntu
    // thus I had to use setlocale();
    char* oldLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"); // let's hope, most machines will have "en_US.UTF-8" available
    // "Works on my machine", that is, Ubuntu 12.04

    size_t wcsSize = wcstombs(conv, src.c_str(), outSize);
    // we might get an error code (size_t-1) in wcsSize, ignoring for now

    // now be good, restore the locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, oldLocale);

    return (access(conv, 0) == 0);

#endif
}
```

And here is some experimental code which led me to the solution:

```
// this is crucial to output correct unicode characters in console and for wcstombs to work!
// empty string also works instead of en_US.UTF-8
// setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

wstring unicoded = wstring(L"/home/progmars/абвгдāēī");
int outSize = unicoded.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) + 1;// max possible bytes plus \0 char
char* conv = new char[outSize]; 
memset(conv, 0, outSize);
size_t szt = wcstombs(conv, unicoded.c_str(), outSize); // this needs setlocale - only then it returns 31. else it returns some big number - most likely, an error message
wcout << "wcstombs result " << szt << endl;

int resDirect = access("/home/progmars/абвгдāēī", 0);   //  works fine always 
int resCast = access((char*)unicoded.c_str(), 0);
int resConv = access(conv, 0);  

wcout << "Raw " << unicoded.c_str() << endl; // output /home/progmars/абвгдāēī but only if setlocale has been called; else output is /home/progmars/????????
wcout << "Casted " << (char*)unicoded.c_str() << endl; // output /      
wcout << "Converted " << conv << endl; // output /home/progmars/ - for some reason, Unicode chars are cut away in the console, but still they are there because access() picks them up correctly

wcout << "resDirect " << resDirect << endl; // gives correct result depending on the file existence 
wcout << "resCast " << resCast << endl; // wrong result  - always 0 because it looks for / and it's the filesystem root which always exists     
wcout << "resConv " << resConv << endl; 
// gives correct result but only if setlocale() is present
```

Of course, I could avoid all that hassle with `ifdef`s to define my own version of string which would be `wstring` on Windows and `string` on *nix because *nix seems to be more liberal about UTF8 symbols and doesn't mind using them in plain strings. Still, I wanted to keep my function declarations consistent for all platforms and also I wanted to learn how Unicode filenames work in Linux.

Comment: This is great.  It really helped me.  Thanks